# Angularjs - Abort/cancel running $http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-resource, angular-http

I've got a call using Resource in angularjs but i get some problems because i can't abort every calls it does. This kind of structure i use for an autocomplete.. is it possible convert from resource call to http? This is the code

```
var Resource = $resource(URL, {},{ getAutocompleteResults: { method: "GET", params: {text: ""} }});

var locked = false;
function getMoreData() {

    if(locked)
        return;
    locked = true;

    Resource.autoCompleteResults()
        .$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data;
            locked = false;
        });

}
```

This is what i've tried so far with no success.

```
$scope.autocompleteViewResults = function () {
            $http
                .get(URL, {
                    params: {
                        text = ""
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data;
                });
        };
```

Or if someone knows an alternative method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$scope.autocompleteViewResults` variable is being assigned 2 times.

Try this:

```
$scope.autocompleteViewResults = {};
$scope.getResults = function(valueAsTyped) {
        $http
            .get(URL, {
                params: {
                    text: valueAsTyped
                }
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data;
            });
  };
```

#### Update

If you need to cancel old requests.

```
var promiseCanceller = $q.defer();
$scope.autocompleteViewResults = {};

$scope.getResults = function(valueAsTyped) {

        promiseCanceller.resolve('request cancelled'); // cancel currently running request
        $http
            .get(URL, {
                params: {
                    text: valueAsTyped
                },
                timeout: promiseCanceller.promise // pass promiseCanceller as the timeout
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data;
            });
  };
```

Comment: tried..but i get a empty string in the querystring. "text"should be the variable i pass in my query when i'm writing.

Comment: perfect it works..the "problem" is still the calls..every time i type something starts a call so i get even 10 calls in queue. have you got a solution maybe using a promise or something other method?

Comment: Updated the answer. I commented the added lines.

Comment: Ahahah now it aborts every call :) from first to last word i type in my input text

Comment: SOLVED! thank you. I created a function with inside 

promiseCanceller.resolve("user cancelled");
                promiseCanceller = $q.defer();

and i call it just before http call. It works!

Comment: How to cancel request with Angular2?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294304/angular2-how-to-abort-cancel-running-http-request-calls

Comment: @End.Game can you update the question with your solution/changes ? I think this accepted answer still needs to add promiseCanceller = $q.defer();