# Angular2 - How to Abort/cancel running http request calls?

Tags: angular

I doing search auto complete.

```
keypress(valueSearch){
   // call Ajax search with ValueSearch
   // ....
}
```

Each time keypress event, i want cancel old http request.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you need to rely on an observable created from the event. If you use the default event binding, you can't have access to this observable. There are opened issues regarding this problem:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5467
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5467

Right now you need to reference the element with the `@ViewChild` decorator and configure an observable on it:

```
@ViewChild('someElt')
someElt: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  Observable.fromEvent(someElt.nativeElement, 'keyup');
}
```

Now you're able to leverage the `switchMap` operator to like an HTTP request on it. If there is an in-progress request in the data flow, it will be canceled:

```
@ViewChild('someElt')
someElt: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  Observable.fromEvent(someElt.nativeElement, 'keyup').switchMap((evt) => {
    return this.http.get('something').map(res => res.json())
  }).subscribe(data => {
    // use data
  });
}
```